# Controlling Sound / Volume

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, actionscript, flash-cc, google-swiffy

I added a sound to the Flash Professional CC library and had the program convert it to MP3. If I create a layer and drag-and-drop the sound onto the stage the sound plays fine (even after passing it through Swiffy), however that is all I am able to do so far.

I need some way to control when the sound plays as well as volume. I tried the giving the sound a class (Sound Properties -> ActionScript -> Export for ActionScript and assigned a class name `mySound`).

Then added this ActionScript to the first frame:

```
var myAudio:Sound = new mySound();
myAudio.play();
```

However, after passing it through Swiffy, I get the following errors:

- The ActionScript class `flash.media.Sound` is not supported.
- The ActionScript method `flash.media.Sound.play()` is not supported.

So I can't use the base Sound class in Flash? Is there another base class that can be used and is it compatible with the `flash.media.Sound` class? Is there some other way to control playback so that it can be played at a specific time -- such as on mouse roll-over or when something is clicked?

Comment: You can do all of the above in Flash, you can't do all of the above after passing a swf through Swiffy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/SoundJS). BTW, Flash Pro CC does have an HTML Canvas document type that uses [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) (which SoundJS is part of) under the hood. It won't convert AS3 to JS, though, you have to write the JS code yourself.

Comment: I am producing an ad so I want to see if there is an easy way to use Swiffy for such things since their Flash ads are now being converted to HTML5 through Swiffy by default: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAds/posts/BWVyFHGUi9n

Comment: Right, and Swiffy is unable to convert all Flash to HTML, as they readily admit. So the HTML version (mobile) won't always automatically work correctly. Alternatively, you can start with Flash HTML Canvas and thus avoid the imperfect Swiffy conversion.

Comment: There would also be no fallback, unless I wrote it myself. I would also have to upload, host, and link to all the resources (images, audio, etc.). Both have drawbacks but I have not received anything overly complex yet so they should work fine with Swiffy. I have been messing with it and found a workable solution using ExternalInterface. The testing tool claims it is not supported but it works and many other people say it has been fully implemented.